# Calculate maximum profit under given path cost

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm

Rooted Graph is given. Here, nodes is "home" that contains some valuable item. Entry node is given, i.e., root of the graph.

Cost is also given to move from one node to other, i.e., Egde weight.

**Question -**

You have to collect maximum valuable item, and total cost should not exceed with given cost.

**Contraint -**
1. There is no cycle.
2. We can use adjancency matrix also.(Total number of vertices is upto 1000).

**Example**

**Edges given with their weight and values present in destination node.**

```
0 1 10 1
0 2 10 15
1 3 50 10
1 4 30 30
```

**Given Cost** = 70.

**Solution** - You will collect node 1, 2, 4's items in a maximum way. **[1+15+30 = 46]**

**My efforts**

I think, this problem will solve by DP, by maintaining some state at every node. But I am not able to make some algorithm. Please help.

**Edit 1**

1. I think this question may be solved by making special graph by using original graph by ading some state into each node.
2. Second approach is, Dynamic programming.

Comment: This is not a homework solution site.  If you tried something, but can't figure out why it isn't working, post your code and we can help highlight deficiencies.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer This is not my homework. Before jumping into code, I was trying to build concrete algorithm. But I failed in that. Please Check Edit 1.

Comment: **Hint:** Have you heard of traveling salesman problem [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem]? This is just a variation of it.

Comment: @noMAD I am not able to connect this problem with salesman problem. Please elaborate more.

Comment: What is the path you're talking about in the solution ? `0->2->0->1->4`? are you paying the edge 0-2 twice (once for going and once for coming back)?

Comment: @6502 No, You can consider edge cost as Zero, for back pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to find an easy solution for this problem.

Consider a graph made by just a root node connected to N leaves. Each leaf has a value of 1 and the edges have cost c1, c2, ... cN.

As you can see this graph problem has the knapsack problem as a special case.

Comment: I understood your point, but here there are internal nodes also present. How can you deal with that ?

Comment: The internal nodes just make the problem more complicated, but not harder. A decision version (can you obtain at least X amount of valuables) is NP-complete whether or not you have internal nodes present.